# ruby nested classes and modules

Tags: ruby

I am familiar with the concept of nesting classes and modules within another module and grouping them in a namespace. What is the idea / purpose behind

1. Nesting classes within another class

   ```
   class A
     class B
       def method_B
         ...
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Nesting modules within another class

   ```
   class A
     module c
       def method_c
         ...
       end
     end
   end
   ```

thanks,
ash

Answer (score 3):

Classes are also namespaces, so it's the same idea. Class is a subclass of Module, so if you get it in the context of modules, you also get it in the context of classes.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about grouping related concerns while exposing sensible semantics.  As an example of number 1 an HTTP::Request (Request class embedded in a larger HTTP protocol class) is a quite different thing from an FTP::Request.  With modules it enables the common ruby idiom of Behavior::InstanceMethods and Behavior::ClassMethods for handling mixins.

Comment: Those are examples of classes within modules, though, while the question is about classes in classes.

Comment: HTTP doesn't have to be a module.  It could be a class depending on how the way you design the program.

Comment: So it is just a namespace and has no special behavior like, only enclosing class being able to create instances of the enclosed class?

Comment: @user290870: You don't nest classes and modules. You nest *constants*. Ruby doesn't have nested classes like Beta or Newspeak.