# how to render a view from the model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to edit a Rails application, but I am a novice when it comes to language (I am new to Ruby & Rails). When viewing the source files I raised some questions:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    class CardRenderer < AbstractController::Base
        include AbstractController::Rendering
        include AbstractController::Helpers

        self.view_paths = Rails.application.config.paths["app/views"]

        helper_method :res_url

        def print(_card, _template)
             @card = _card
             render template: "prints/#{_template}.html"
        end

        protected
            def res_url(_res_name)
                "#{Rails.root}/app/views/prints/res/#{_res_name}"
            end
     end
     .......
     .......
     .......
end
```

I saw a model that contained a classe inside another class 
Do you have a name this language feature?

How I can call this class from an instance of the model?
for example from the controller (Obviously this does not work):

```
@card::CardRenderer.new.print(@card, @template)
```

The class that is inside the model class has a function that renders a view

I can make use this function from the controller?
for example from the controller (obviously this does not work either)

```
render Card::CardRenderer.new.print(@card, @template)
```

Is that the ideal is that I read a book!, And I'll do it! but in these days I can not (timing problems).

Comment: I can tell you right now that this isn't standard rails practice. It is probably specific to your workplace. It may also qualify for thedailywtf.

Comment: As to how nested classes work in ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832320/ruby-nested-classes-and-modules

Comment: You seem to have stuffed a half-dozen questions into one here. Most of which have nothing to do with your title. Don’t do that (it’s called a *question* not a *questions*, after all).

Comment: Thanks, his comments were of great help. I'll be more careful next time to write my questions

Answer (score 1):

*Do you have a name for this language feature?*

"nested classes", I think

*How I can call this class from an instance of the model?*

`@card.class::CardRenderer` should work

*The class that is inside the model class has a function that renders a view. Can I use this function from the controller?*

Read the whole thing start to finish: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

---

p.s. I have a sneaking suspicion the current design of the app goes completely against the ideas of Model-View-Controller